# Как вставить WebView во фрагмент

Tags: android, java

Вот код фрагмента, все импорты прописаны, но при запуску вылетает ошибка.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
WebView webPage;
public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    webPage = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webPage);
    // включаем поддержку JavaScript
    webPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // указываем страницу загрузки
    webPage.loadUrl("http://site.ru");

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView у вас в fragment_home? Тогда так:

```
webPage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webPage);
```